# Handle Transaction Between Multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, mongodb, transactions

consider I have a database for my application data which is mysql and I have another database for my logging purpose which is mongodb.

how can I handle transaction between these two databases.
for example lets assume that I want to delete a single record in mysql database and insert a new record in mongodb database (new log record).
how can I be assured from Data Integrity?
how can I make sure log record is inserted only if database has been deleted successfully.

Comment: Not posting as an answer, because I don't have anything specifically for PHP, but in general, you're talking about "[distributed transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction)". These generally require a third-party "coordinator" that manages the transactions. This is also commonly called a [two phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an architecture that requires a transaction between mysql and mongodb seems to be your problem. In a distributed system, that this seems to be, it's more normal to be *eventually consistent*. It's very difficult to be transactional *AND* distributed. Perhaps you could use some kind of event sourcing to raise a *delete record event* that will *eventually* delete a record from MySql and *eventually* log a delete entry to MongoDb.

Alternatively you could implement a SAGA or Workflow solution to manage the *transaction* across the two data sources and retry the log entry a certain number of times and compensate if necessary when it can't be done.

Comment: eventually I got to the same solution as you said,
thanks.